# Search metadata in all server-side files in subfolder NOT using FileSystem API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a server-side subfolder structure in my HTML5/JS site.

The subfolder structure contains various media types where each media file is wrapped in its own HTML file which contains metatags.

I want to list all metatags for all files but I do not want to have to browse for a file (i.e. no FileSystem API) and get it's metadata. I just want to scan through the subfolder and list all metadata in each file.

I'm not able to find any script to do this, everything I keep running into is asking for the FileSystem API and the requirement to browse for a file.

alternatively, if FileSystem API can do this, I'd use it as long as I don't have to go browsing for files to use it.

My server is a standard LAMP server and the files are all HTML files inside a site subfolder. This site currently has no DB and I'm hoping to not add one for this functionality.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of server? You need to give more context for people to understand your problem.

Comment: @pvoosten Thanks for asking. Just a LAMP server - nothing special with the server or my project files. HTML5/JS/jQuery. Currently no DB either. All I want to do is display the metadata of all files within a subfolder in the site. Later, I'll add search functionality, but for now, just getting the metadata is enough. The data would be stuff like keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Node.js would be a good fit for you. Then you can write everything in Javascript. It is server side scripting, but for demonstration purposes the configuration is much easier than Apache.

---

If I understand correctly that you don't want to browse the file system on the server side, but on the client side you are willing to do anything with Javascript, then the following may also be an option.

Using LAMP, you can configure Apache so that it shows directory indexes (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex), which you can use to browse to the content you need on the client side.

---

In any case, you will have to hit the files on your server somehow, either directly through the file system on the server side or with an HTTP request from the client side.

Comment: Thanks again for the feedback. I'm using a USB server (this is for an instructor in a classroom to look up / present /project information relative to his/her instructional content. I could configure the USB web server a bit, but nodeJS is not an option. Using FileTree.js, I'm already dealing with listing file names (less the extension) and displaying file contents in an iFrame. This works fine for me. I'm only seeking a solution to look inside those file for metadata (I'm using a search form). I may have found a PHP script that solves this and am currently trying that solution.